# CSS Grid Issues

Tags: css, css-grid

Basically this page is just a mess and I probably need general advice in addition to the particular problem.

Trying to code a standard Header, Hero image, then I want to put text and linked images below (haven't gotten that far yet). I'll tell sections to go to a certain row and column and they don't necessarily go there.

Also, when I try to view in Chrome Dev for mobile, the view is always zoomed in and I'm not sure why. I tried changing the child `divs` to figure tags and things got worse, so I changed them back: not sure what that's about.

Also, I've put that I want the grid to be 100% vh and vw, but it's not.

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="icon" href="Logo2.jpeg">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>PancakeArtwork.com Learning Page</title>
  <style>
    /*Mobile Style*/
    
    body {
      font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
      /*  background-image: radial-gradient(circle at 50% 34%, #cab062, #b38454, #99744f, #926252,#906050,#875647, #907551);*/
    }
    
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    .learningGrid {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
      grid-template-rows: 15vh 15vh 15vh 15vh 15vh;
      height: 100vh;
      width: 100vw;
    }
    
    .header {
      grid-column: 1 / span 12;
      grid-row: 1 / span 2;
      background-color: gold;
      height: 15vh;
      width: 100vw;
      min-height: 1px;
    }
    
    .logo {
      grid-column: 1 / 4;
      width: 15vw;
      height: 15vh;
    }
    
    .title {
      grid-column-start: 2;
      grid-column-end: 10;
      grid-row-start: 1;
      grid-row-end: 2;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 4vw;
      color: brown;
    }
    
    .aboutUs {
      grid-column-start: 10;
      grid-column-end: 12;
      grid-row-start: 1;
      grid-row-end: 2;
      font-size: 3vw;
      color: brown;
    }
    
    .hero {
      grid-column-start: 1;
      grid-column-end: 12;
      grid-row-start: 2;
      grid-row-end: 4;
    }
    
    .adviceColumn {
      grid-column-start: 1;
      grid-column-end: 3;
      grid-row-start: 4;
      grid-row-end: 5;
      font-size: 5vw;
      justify-content: center;
      align-content: center;
      color: brown;
    }
    
    .newsColumn {
      grid-column-start: 3;
      grid-column-end: 6;
      grid-row-start: 4;
      grid-row-end: 5;
      font-size: 5vw;
      justify-content: center;
      align-content: center;
      color: brown;
    }
    
    .communityColumn {
      grid-column-start: 6;
      grid-column-end: 9;
      grid-row-start: 4;
      grid-row-end: 5;
      font-size: 5vw;
      justify-content: center;
      align-content: center;
      color: brown;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="learningGrid">
    <div class="header">
      <div class="logo">
        <a href="index.html" title="PancakeArtwork.com navigation page"><img src="Logo2.jpeg" class="logo" alt="PancakeArtwork.com - Navigation Page"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="title">PancakeArtwork.com <br> Learning Page</div>
      <div class="aboutUs">About Us</div>
    </div>


    <div class="hero"><img src="books2.jpg" alt="Picture of Books to Represent Learning" ;></div>
    <main>
      <div class="adviceColumn">Advice</div>
      <div class="newsColumn">News</div>
      <div class="communityColumn">Community</div>
    </main>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The main issue I think you're having with this is that `learningGrid` only has three direct children: `header`, `hero`, and `main`. When you set it to display a grid, only those three children can be given positions within the grid. You can use further grids on each of those elements to position their children in turn.

Comment: Thank you Lazarus. I'm guessing the reason it kept zooming in was because of the image size (I hadn't sized it yet).

After wrestling for hours with CSS grid, I finally just used a table with old fashioned HTML/CSS and knocked out the page in less than an hour. So I will probably just avoid grid in the future. 
This was my first post here: I appreciate your taking the time to respond and will vote/upvote/or whatever I can to your post. Thank you.

Comment: Glad you got something to work in the end, although I would recommend learning CSS grid if you can as it is much more flexible and powerful than HTML tables which are kind of redundant when it comes to modern web design.

Answer (score 0):

@Lazarus The main issue I think you're having with this is that learningGrid only has three direct children: header, hero, and main. When you set it to display a grid, only those three children can be given positions within the grid. You can use further grids on each of those elements to position their children in turn. – Lazarus 2 days ago

Comment: Lazarus had some great feedback. Ultimately creating a table with CSS was much more efficient for me than trying to structure using Grid, so I ditched the grid and placed items using a table.